# How can i get all rows that have certain cell value of an excel file using java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to find all rows that have same cell value (exp value1) , so for example i want to search through:
row1 cell1value cell2value ... value1
row2 ......................... value2
row3 ......................... value3
row4 ......................... value1

and get row1 and row2

The code below returns only the first row that has the desired value , how to improve it to do what i need ?

```
package questbarreader;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class QuestBarReader {
public static String folder = "D:\\Test";
public static String extension = "";
//THIS is the method i use to get row that has specific cell value
public static int findRow(Sheet sheet, String cellContent) {
for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            if(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().contains(cellContent)) {
                return row.getRowNum();

            }
        }
    }
}               
return 0;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    Iterator it = FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File(folder), null, false);

    while(it.hasNext()){
        String fileName = ((File) it.next()).getName();
        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        if(i>0){extension = fileName.substring(i+1);}
        if((fileName.startsWith("sal"))&& extension.equals("xls")){
            String path = (folder + "\\" + fileName);

            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(path));
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int totalRows = sheet.getLastRowNum();

            int qUltraEnergy = findRow(sheet, "Q ULTRA ENERGY");
            String qUltraEnergyValue = sheet.getRow(qUltraEnergy).getCell(13).getStringCellValue();
            String delims = "[x]+";
            String[] tokens = qUltraEnergyValue.split(delims);
            double kom = Double.valueOf(tokens[0]);

        }
    }  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the row number, you need to add it to a List, and then return the List once you've gone through all of the rows.

```
public static List<Integer> findRows(Sheet sheet, String cellContent) {
    List<Integer> matchedRows = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                if(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().contains(cellContent)) {
                    // return row.getRowNum(); Instead of this...
                    matchedRows.add(row.getRowNum()); // Add the row to the list of matches
                }
            }
        }
    }               
    return matchedRows; // will be empty if no matches are found
}
```

Afterwards, you can iterate over the list of all matches.